# Санта Мария, санта Мария или Санта-Мария?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Речь идет о названиях западных церквей. Например, церковь Сан-Марко или Сан Марко? Или сан Марко? То же самое с Санта-Марией и т.д.
По идее, по-русски в аналогичном случае пишется раздельно и с маленькой буквы, например, "храм святого Николая". Тогда, по логике, западные названия тоже должны писаться "храм санта Марии"?
Как на самом деле правильно и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно - **Санта-Мария**. В русском языке нет слова "санта", поэтому при заимствовании названий без перевода "санта" неотделимо от всего имени собственного и пишется через дефис. Тоже самое касается и большей части других заимствованных терминов из нескольких слов (*Гранд-Опера, Нью-Йорк* и пр.).